# How to change the innerText of an <a> using javascript

Tags: javascript

When I click on the "show details" link it should change to "hide details". I tried the following code but it's not working:

```
out.print("<a href=\"javascript:parent.showHideDetails('"+id+"',this);\">show details</a>");

function showHideDetails(id,obj) {
    try
    {

        alert(obj.innerText);
        obj.innerText = 'hide details';
    }
    catch (err)
    {
        alert(err);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `this` in your href attribute doesn't point to the anchor. You could pass an identifier there, and give the anchor element the same identified as `id` attribute; and then use document.getElementById to get the anchor.

Example:

```
out.print("<a href=\"javascript:parent.showHideDetails('"+id+"','anchor_1');\" id=\"anchor_1\">show details</a>");

function showHideDetails(id,identifier) {
    try
    {
        var obj = document.getElementById(identifier);
        alert(obj.innerText);
        obj.innerText = 'hide details';
    }
    catch (err)
    {
        alert(err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The details in your question are sparse. Here are a few possibilities:

Remove `parent.` from the inline handler, and change it to an `onclick`:

```
"<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"javascript:showHideDetails('"+id+"',this);\">show details</a>"
```

Perhaps the `showHideDetails()` function isn't global

Perhaps `innerText` isn't supported in the browser you're using. Try `innerHTML` instead.

```
obj.innerHTML = 'hide details';
```

Answer (score 1):

InnerText is one of those browser finicky ones that are named differently in different browsers.  If you are just getting started with javascript I would recommend using a framework like [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) because it's far simpler to call a function like:

```
$('#linkID').text('show');
```

Than it is to get each browser variant set properly.  The framework does all that for you.

Answer (score 0):

`this` will point to DOM window and not the `<a>` tag. So use `onclick` attribute to execute.

```
out.print("<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"showHideDetails('"+id+"',this);\">
show details</a>");
```